# Error message not appearing when details entered incorrectly

Tags: php

I have a login form and it works fine when users enter the correct username and password but nothing happens when the wrong information is entered. How would I get an error message to  appear. I have "Login failed" as shown below but this doesnt work for some reason. Any help much appreciated.

```
<?php 
require("config.php"); 
$submitted_username = ''; 

if(!empty($_POST)){ 
    $query = "SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username"; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 

    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $login_ok = false; 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ 
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
        } 
        if($check_password === $row['password']){
            $login_ok = true;
        } 
    } 

    if($login_ok){ 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row;  
        header("Location: secret.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to: secret.php"); 
    } 
    else{ 
        print("Login Failed."); 
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
   }
} 

?>
```

Comment: what is `$round < 65536` doing?

Comment: It for salt I believe

Comment: You tagged this jquery. Is the login happening from  a jquery call?

Comment: no tagged jquery by accident sorry

Comment: So what does happen on a failed login?

Comment: Yes, what does occur when you put the wrong password in?

Comment: Also, rehashing your password 65536 times seems like overkill to me

Comment: When I put in the wrong details the page just refreshes and nothing happens

Comment: echo '<h1 style="color:red;font-weight:bold; margin-top:100px;">Login Failed</h1>';  When i put that code in the message displayed. It appears it was hidden behind something